# Strange issue using PropertyInfo in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I have a class like so:

```
public class CompanyData
    {
        # region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// string CompanyNumber
        /// </summary>
        private string strCompanyNumber;    

        /// <summary>
        /// string CompanyName
        /// </summary>
        private string strCompanyName;

    [Info("companynumber")]
    public string CompanyNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.strCompanyNumber;
        }

        set
        {
            this.strCompanyNumber = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets CompanyName
    /// </summary>
    [Info("companyName")]
    public string CompanyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.strCompanyName;
        }

        set
        {
            this.strCompanyName = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the CompanyData class
    /// </summary>
    public CompanyData()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the CompanyData class 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other"> object company data</param>
    public CompanyData(CompanyData other)
    {
        this.Init(other);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// sets the Company data attributes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">object company data</param>
    protected void Init(CompanyData other)
    {
        this.CompanyNumber = other.CompanyNumber;
        this.CompanyName = other.CompanyName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Getting array of entity properties
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An array of PropertyInformation</returns>
    public PropertyInfo[] GetEntityProperties()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] thisPropertyInfo;

        thisPropertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties();

        return thisPropertyInfo;
    }

    }
```

A csv file is read and a collection of CompanyData objects is created

In this method I am trying to get properties and values:

```
private void GetPropertiesAndValues(List<CompanyData> resList)
{

        foreach (CompanyData resRow in resList)
        {

            this.getProperties = resRow.ExternalSyncEntity.GetEntityProperties();

            this.getValues = resRow.ExternalSyncEntity.GetEntityValue(resRow.ExternalSyncEntity);

         }
 }
```

Here's the problem, for the first object the `GetEntityProperties()` returns the `CompanyNumber` as the first element in the array. For the remaining objects it returns `CompanyName` as the first element.

Why is the sequence not consistent?

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

The [Type.GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) does not return ordered result.

> > The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies.

If you want to use ordered/consistent result, it is better to sort the returned array.

Comment: A common approach is to introduce some kind of ordering atribute on Properties i.e. [Order(int)]

Comment: Or sort them by name.